# Немного не ясны условия выполнения задачи (ЕГЭ инфа)

Tags: python

Дан целочисленный массив из 40 элементов. Элементы массива могут принимать целые значения от 0 до 10 000 включительно. Опишите на естественном языке или на одном из языков программирования алгоритм, который находит количество элементов массива, меньших 100, не делящихся на 3, после чего заменяет в массиве соответствующие значения на найденное количество. После чего выводит полученный массив на экран.

```
Python
# допускается также
# использовать две
# целочисленные
# переменные j, k
a = []
n = 40
for i in range(n):
     a.append(int(input()))
...
```

Вот прога

```
n = 5
a = []
k = 0
for i in range (n):
    a.append(int(input()))

for j in a:
    if j % 3 != 0 and j < 100:
        k += 1

for i in range (n):
    if a[i] % 3 != 0 and a[i] < 100:
        a[i] = k

print (a)
```

Я использовал i два раза, но не знаю, правильно ли это? Вопрос больше для тех, кто сдавал егэ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А причем тут повторное использование i? В программировании любую переменную можно использовать повторно, если это не противоречит семантике алгоритма. У вас не противоречит. Значит формально - программа написана правильно.

Другое дело, что правильно - это еще не значит оптимально.

Ниже версия  вашей программы, в которой не три, а два цикла. Да, на 5 или 40 элементах -  ерунда, а вот если их 5 миллионов.... И надо в себе с самого начала развивать умение искать оптимальные или хотя-бы наиболее эффективные алгоритмы.

```
n = 5
a = []
k = 0
for i in range (n):
    a.append(int(input()))  
    if a[i]% 3 != 0 and a[i] < 100:
        k += 1
for i in range (n):
    if a[i] % 3 != 0 and a[i] < 100:
        a[i] = k
print (a)
```

И да, специально для вас :-) с повторным использованием переменной.

Можно пойти еще дальше, и написать программу с (почти) одним циклом - правда для этого придется задействовать дополнительную память, а я не знаю, как к этому относится ЕГЭ:

```
n = 5
a = []
c=[]
k = 0
for i in range (n):
    a.append(int(input()))  
    if a[i]% 3 != 0 and a[i] < 100:
        k += 1
        c.append(i)       
for i in c:
    a[i]=k
print (a)
```

При определенных условиях эта версия будет работать на много быстрее первой и второй. И мне кажется, при обучении программированию надо оценивать вот такие умения ученика, а не то использует-ли он переменную повторно.